# updating html when a variable changes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code for a clicker game i am working on and i need the displayed html to update when the variable changes

This is my javascript:

```
var carparts = 0
document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;

function onButtonClick() {
  carparts = carparts + 1
  alert(carparts)}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
```

and this is my html:

```
<p id="karpartz"></p>
<button>
button
</button>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(karpartz)
      </script>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i get this to work if it even possible?

i cant find anything to help me and i am super stuck. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the HTML content inside the onButtonClick function. Currently, you're only updating the carparts variable but not updating the HTML content. Here's the modified JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var carparts = 0;
document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;
function onButtonClick() {
    carparts = carparts + 1;
    document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts; // Update the HTML content
alert(carparts);
}

const button = document.querySelector('button'); 
  button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick); 
</script>


<p id="karpartz"></p>
<button>button</button>
```

When the button is clicked, the onButtonClick function is called, which increments the carparts variable and updates the HTML content to reflect the new value of carparts.